# Stop/prevent page/body height change when hiding an element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I have some drag-and-drop elements on a page whose `ondragstart` function causes a child section to collapse, which is changing the height of the page, forcing an auto-scroll if the user is far enough down the page, which cancels the dragging, so the user has to try again. And worse, if the user happens to scroll back to the bottom and try dragging again, the whole process happens again.

**Is there something I can put into my `ondragstart` (or maybe `onmousedown`?) function that prevents body resizing until `onmouseup` or something?**

I suppose if this isn't possible, I'll have to figure out a way to have the draggable element's parent not resize...

Comment: Change line 37.

Comment: I realize that I didn't include any code, I was just wondering whether there was a method for the `window` or the body `element` that I was unaware of to prevent reflow when an element's `display` is set to 'none'.

Comment: Why not use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`? When `visibility` is `hidden`, the element is not visible, but still occupies the same space on the page.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap's Collapse/Show to hide elements. And I just realized that there really is no solution, here, because some of the elements are multiple screen-heights long before collapsing, so if I prevented the body from resizing, any elements below it wouldn't be visible to the user for the drag/drop sorting. Thanks for helping me think more critically about it.